# Isolating Values in Python Dictionary List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to write the code for most flexible eater as the organism that eats the greatest number of other organisms in the food chain which happens to be the bird

So far the code I have written is:

---

```
foodweb = {}

with open('AquaticFoodWeb.txt') as input:
    for line in input:
        animal, prey = line.strip().split(' eats ')
        foodweb.setdefault(animal, []).append(prey)

print ("Predators and Prey:")

for animal, prey in sorted(foodweb.items()):
    if len(prey) > 1:
        print ("{} eats {} and {}".format(animal, ", ".join(prey[:-1]),     prey[-1]))
    else:
        print ("{} eats {}".format(animal, ", ".join(prey)))


print (" ")

#Apex

values = [item.strip() for sub in foodweb.values() for item in sub]
for apex in foodweb.keys():
    if apex.strip() not in values:
        print("Apex Predators: ", apex)


print (" ")       


#Producers
producers = []
allpreys = [item.strip() for sub in foodweb.values() for item in sub]
for p in allpreys:
    if p.strip() not in foodweb.keys() and p not in producers:
        producers.append(p)

print("The Producers Are:")
print(formatList(producers))
```

---

So I've written the code for isolating Apex Predators and Producers and was wondering if the code needed to write the flexible eat is along the lines of this? I apologize for not having attempted writing the flexible eater code, I don't understand what part of the keys and values need to be entered in order to isolate the bird value.

**For reference this is the list:**

```
Bird eats Prawn
Bird eats Mussels
Bird eats Crab
Bird eats Limpets
Bird eats Whelk
Crab eats Mussels
Crab eats Limpets
Fish eats Prawn
Limpets eats Seaweed
Lobster eats Crab
Lobster eats Mussels
Lobster eats Limpets
Lobster eats Whelk
Mussels eats Phytoplankton
Mussels eats Zooplankton
Prawn eats Zooplankton
Whelk eats Limpets
Whelk eats Mussels
Zooplankton eats Phytoplankton
```

**And the output is supposed to say:**

Most Flexible Eaters: Bird

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `cut -d " " -f 1 thelist | sort | uniq -c` this is so trivial it doesn't even need Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate this value directly from your existing `foodweb` dictionary as follows:

```
print("Most Flexible Eaters: {}".format(sorted(foodweb.items(), key=lambda x: -len(x[1]))[0][0]))
```

This would display:

```
Most Flexible Eaters: Bird
```

This works by sorting the dictionary items by the length of their values and selecting the first item in the list.

To avoid the use of a `lambda` it could be written as follows:

```
def get_length(x):
    return -len(x[1])

print("Most Flexible Eaters: {}".format(sorted(foodweb.items(), key=get_length)[0][0]))
```

Note, adding a `-` to the returned length is just a trick to reverse the sort order, alternatively `reverse=True` could be added as an argument to the sort to have the same effect.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with using lambda, is this beneficial?

Comment: It is a way of making a self-contained function. It could be replaced with a call to a separate function called say `get_length`.